# Changing the color setting Ubuntu Libre/Office

Tags: libreoffice

Hi so in my libre office docx document, the page went completely black.   when i open the document using microsoft online i can read it normally.

I tried changing the background color to no avail.  need help!

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall and re-install a newer version of libreoffice to resolve this issue.